# How to generate array of keys with matching values in two different arrays

Tags: php

Match two arrays values and generate the array of keys whos values are same
I manage to solve this as described below but, both array may contain huge records,
So can anyone suggest the more optimized solution?
result should be same as now

```
$arr1 = array(
    105 => '101,Utility,\N',
    102 => '101,Utility,\N',
    103 => '105,Parker,Peter',
    104 => 'Rahul Ippar'
);

$arr2 = array(
    108 => '101,Utility1,Floor',
    120 => '101,Utility2,\N',
    130 => '105,Parker,Peter',
    140 => 'Rahul Ippar'
);

$arr3 = array_intersect( $arr2, $arr1 );
$arr4 = array_flip( $arr1 );

foreach( $arr3 as $k => $v ) {
    $arr3[$k] = $arr4[$v];
}

print_r($arr3);
```

Result should be same as below

```
Array
(
    [130] => 103
    [140] => 104
)
```

Comment: SO isn't a free code optimization site.

Comment: Do it yourself and come back again if you face issues with your own solution.

Comment: And it's unlikely someone would come up with an alternative, unless you explain the procedure and goal.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be:

```
$result = array_combine(
    array_keys(array_intersect( $arr2, $arr1 )),
    array_keys(array_intersect( $arr1, $arr2 ))
);
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/ErRID)

whether it's any faster or more memory efficient, I don't know, though it should be because it's using fewer copies of the data (so less memory usage), and fewer loops; but that's something you'd need to test with your volumes of data